# Laravel UNION ALL not working with where statement

Tags: php, laravel, where-clause, laravel-5.1, union-all

I want to get two queues into one.

```
$buildings_queue=IngameBuildingQueue::where(DB::raw('UNIX_TIMESTAMP(`start_time` + `duration`)'),'<=',time());
$recruit_queue=IngameRecruitQueue::where(DB::raw('UNIX_TIMESTAMP(`start_time` + `duration`)'),'<=',time());
$queue=$buildings_queue->unionAll($recruit_queue);
dd($queue->toSql());
```

Laravel throw:

> [ErrorException]  Undefined property: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder::$bindings

but when I delete `where()` methods everything works fine.

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the Laravel user manual this should work

```php
IngameRecruitQueue::where(DB::raw('UNIX_TIMESTAMP(`start_time` + `duration`)'),'<=',time())->union($buildings_queue)->get();
```

---

Also try to write your variables in camelCase convention

**$buildings_queue** will be **$buildingsQueue**

*check this answer to learn more: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/196463*